# Lead conversion - lead owner

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, ownership

When a Lead is converted in Salesforce, you can select a Record Owner for the new objects. 
-What happens to the owner field of the Lead? Will the Lead always be reassigned to the chosen Record Owner? Or will it still be owned by its current owner (e.g. the queue)?

Answer (score 1):

The lead owner remains the same it was on the moment of conversion.

If you don't specify a different owner for the new objects, they will be also owned by the lead owner.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @nocovi's answer --

Converted Leads can not be viewed on a standard Lead page layout; nor will they be found in a search.  Except for reporting or APEX/SOQL, converted Leads 'disappear' for most use cases - the data having been copied to Account-Contact-Opportunity

see [SFDC Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_notes.htm&language=en_US) for more details about Lead Conversion Considerations